# HTML Change Image with transition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've been experimenting with HTML5 for a bit, and i wanted to try to make an **Image** change when a mouse **hovers** over it. I've tried a couple of methods and none of them gave the desired effect. I've looked through multiple tutorials but they mostly explained how to add effects to the same Image, and not change it entirely.

This is the code i have now, it doesnt actually work as intended:

```css
ul.imagetransition li img:hover {
  background-image: url('Data/Images/Image 1Hover.png');
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul class="imagetransition">
    <li><a href="http://testlink.com"><img src="Data/Images/Image 1.png"/></a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

In this code, the original image is previewed correctly, but when the mouse hovers over it it **immediately** adds a small **part** of the **second image** onto the first one. I've tried adding the transition effect code, but it didnt have any effect. I'll be doing more research regarding this, if anyone knows/understands how to get this done, please point me to the right directions! :D

Please let me know if further Information/Code is needed

Greatly appreciated,
Have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work for you?

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="aaa">
      <img class="bottom" src="a.jpg">
      <img class="top" src="b.jpg">
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#aaa {
  position:relative;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  margin:0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#aaa img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#aaa img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, i Believe that would work too. But is there a way to get this effect while keeping the **UnorderedList**?

Comment: Yes, it worked on an empty HTML page. But for some reason when i implement this code on my current HTML page, none of those 2 images appear. I've even checked the Z-index, but it probably isnt the case

Comment: I've experimented for a bit and apparently when i remove this line of code, the images appear and transition perfectly..

    `ul.aaa li {

 display: inline;
    }`

But now the positioning of any new images in UnorderedList wont be positioned as intended.. I'll continue playing around and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: You can always try checking with developers tools if any other element from your site is not interferencing with the new part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

From past experiences this won't work unless you use JS's getElementById and change the src of the background image. Either that or use a two in one kind of thing like

```html
<div id="parent1">
<ul></ul>
</div>
```

Where if you hover over it the first one's background would have an opacity of 0 and the ul's opacity to one by using parent/child relation and activation  or maybe try add `!important` at the end of the second background image  restrictions like padding won't work coz that would only separate your images even more.

Hope this helps.

Ps: I was writing this on my phone :/ but now i edited it using my laptop

here are some examples using JS

[the mouseover thing](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover)

[and this is for the change image thing](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_backgroundimage)

i think you can piece these together finely.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<img class="bottom" src="a.jpg">
```

CSS

```
img
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
    transition: width 2s;
}
img:hover {
    width: 300px;
}
```